# Reading string from the URL using $.getJSON

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, vb.net

I created a web service that is setting on different project and returning me a string by passing 2 param:
{"PersonID":132,"Title":"Security Officer","Company":"TCA","CellNum":"999-999-9999","EmergencyPhone":"","Email":""}

The thing is I'm trying to read that string from another project using Javascript in that JS function I tried to use $.getJSON on the url in order to get the actually string but
I can't!! I think that I'm not reading it properly.... how can I read the string from the URL????

```
WebService:

    <OperationContract()>
    <WebInvoke(Method:="GET", UriTemplate:="/getPersonInfo/?personID={personID}&companyCode={companyCode}", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)>
    Public Function getPersonInfo(ByVal personID As String, ByVal companyCode As String) As String
        Dim dba As New DBAccess
        Dim m_SelPerson As String = String.Empty
        Dim ds As DataSet = dba.GetPersonInfo(personID, companyCode)
        If Not ds Is Nothing Then
            Dim dr As DataRow = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)
            Dim person As New PersonInfo
            person.PersonID = Convert.ToInt32(dr("PersonID"))
            person.Company = dr("Company")
            person.Title = dr("Title")
            person.CellNum = dr("CellNum")
            person.EmergencyPhone = dr("EmergencyPhone")
            person.Email = dr("Email")
            Dim oSerilzer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
            m_SelPerson = oSerilzer.Serialize(person)
        End If
        Return m_SelPerson
    End Function




JS function

 function GetPersonInfo() {
        var url = "http://123.1456.12434/getPersonInfo/personid=125&companycode=TCA&sensor=false";
        $ = jQuery;
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
       console.log(data); 
        });
//        alert(obj['Company']);
//        $ = jQuery;
//        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
//            for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
////                var personInfo = data.results[i];

//                fnCallback(pinfo);
//                return false;
//            }
//        });
    }
```

Comment: Is `http://123.1456.12434/` the same site as page or other one? Does that service allow cross domain calls with CORS if it is on other domain?

Comment: I just worte something hard coded for that problem I have I don't to expose that actual url..... the thing is I maybe trying to use  $.getJSON(url) which is wrong..... how can I get the string in JS function??

Comment: when I click view source I'm getting something like that:  <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">{"PersonID":132,"Title":"Security Officer","Company":"TCA","CellNum":"999-999-9999","EmergencyPhone":"","Email":""}</string>

Comment: Not sure why you can't answer "if url is on the same domain as page or not", but indeed it is ok. Try to debug and at least see if there are any exceptions. Use Fiddler  to see if request is made and response is ok. Good luck.